# Swift - Initialise model object with init(from decoder:)

Tags: ios, swift, jsondecoder

Below is my model struct

```swift
struct MovieResponse: Codable {
    
    var totalResults: Int
    var response: String
    var error: String
    var movies: [Movie]
    
    enum ConfigKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalResults
        case response = "Response"
        case error = "Error"
        case movies
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.totalResults = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .totalResults)!
        self.response = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .response)!
        self.error = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error) ?? ""
        self.movies = try values.decodeIfPresent([Movie].self, forKey: .movies)!
    }
}

extension MovieResponse {
    struct Movie: Codable, Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var title: String
        var year: Int8
        var imdbID: String
        var type: String
        var poster: URL
        
        enum EncodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case title = "Title"
            case year = "Year"
            case imdmID
            case type = "Type"
            case poster = "Poster"
        }
    }
}
```

Now in a ViewModel, I am creating an instance of this model using the below code

```swift
@Published var movieObj = MovieResponse()
```

But there is a compile error saying, call `init(from decoder)` method. What is the proper way to create a model instance in this case?

Comment: Unrelated but force unwrapping a value decoded by `decodeIfPresent` is pointless. Remove `IfPresent` and the trailing exclamation mark. Instead of raising a crash the line will throw an error if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) reads:

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that provides default values for all of its properties and doesn’t provide at least one initializer itself.

The **"and doesn’t provide at least one initializer itself"** part is crucial here. Since you are declaring an additional initializer you should either declare your own initialized like so:

```swift
init(
    totalResults: Int,
    response: String,
    error: String,
    movies: [Movie]
) {
    self.totalResults = totalResults
    self.response = response
    self.error = error
    self.movies = movies
}
```

or move `Codable` conformance to an extension so Swift can provide you with a default initialiser. This would be a preferred way to do it (my personal opinion, I like to move additional protocol conformances to extensions).

```swift
struct MovieResponse {
    var totalResults: Int
    var response: String
    var error: String
    var movies: [Movie]
}

extension MovieResponse: Codable {

    enum ConfigKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalResults
        case response = "Response"
        case error = "Error"
        case movies
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.totalResults = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .totalResults)!
        self.response = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .response)!
        self.error = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error) ?? ""
        self.movies = try values.decodeIfPresent([Movie].self, forKey: .movies)!
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is good and working. But when I use the second one, it is still the same error.

Comment: I think you meant to write `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add another initializer if you do not want to use a decoder. Swift give you one for free if and only if you do not write your own initializer. Now that you have one you loose the free one.

add another:

```
init() {
    //Your initializer code here
}
```

If you are trying to use the decoder init you need to use a decoder to invoke it. For instance if it's Json

```
@Published var movieObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MovieResponse.self, from: <#T##Data#>)
```